# Avoiding small files from Kafka connect using HDFS connector sink in distributed mode

Tags: apache-kafka, hdfs, kafka-producer-api, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

We have a topic with messages at the rate of 1msg per second with 3 partitions and I am using HDFS connector to write the data to HDFS as AVRo format(default), it generates files with size in KBS,So I tried altering the below properties in the HDFS properties.

**"flush.size":"5000", 
"rotate.interval.ms":"7200000"**

but the output is still small files,So I need clarity on the following things to solve this issue:

1. is flush.size property mandatory, in-case if we do not mention the flus.size property how does the data gets flushed?
2. if the we mention the flush size as 5000 and rotate interval as 2 hours,it is flushing the data for every 2 hours for first 3 intervals but after that it flushes data randomly,Please find the timings of the file creation(
   19:14,21:14,23:15,**01:15,06:59,08:59**,12:40,14:40)--highlighted the mismatched intervals.is it because of the over riding of properties mentioned?that takes me to the third question.
3. What is the preference for flush if we mention all the below properties (flush.size,rotate.interval.ms,rotate.schedule.interval.ms)
4. Increasing the rate of msg and reducing the partition is actually showing an increase in the size of the data being flushed, is it the only way to have control over the small files,how can we handle the properties if the rate of the input events are varying and not stable?

It would be great help if you could share documentations regarding handling small files in kafka connect with HDFS connector,Thank you.

Comment: Try to use the TimeBasedPartitioner rather than the default. And these are the only properties to accomodate file writing at the moment. It isn't Kafka's job to write large files (you can do this downstream in any Hadoop processing), you just tune Connect to batch for longer. Additionally, we have the same problem with S3 Connect -- If the timestamp extractor sees times are not always increasing ("late events" come into Kafka), then the files are flushing immediately when that record is seen.

Comment: Did you get chance to look at point 2 and 3,the preference of the properties mentioned?

Comment: Last time I looked at the code, I believe it was scheduled rotation takes precedence over the other, then flush size is checked before either time settings. In the end, each boolean condition is OR-d together

Answer (score 4):

If you are using a TimeBasedPartitioner, and the messages are not consistently going to have increasing timestamps, then you will end up with a single writer task dumping files when it sees a message with a lesser timestamp in the interval of `rotate.interval.ms` of reading any given record.

If you want to have consistent bihourly partition windows, then you should be using `rotate.interval.ms=-1` to disable it, then `rotate.schedule.interval.ms` to some reasonable number that is within the partition duration window.

E.g. you have 7200 messages every 2 hours, and it's not clear how large each message is, but let's say 1MB. Then, you'd be holding ~7GB of data in a buffer, and you need to adjust your Connect heap sizes to hold that much data.

The order of presecence is

1. scheduled rotation, starting from the top of the hour
2. flush size or "message-based" time rotation, whichever occurs first, or there is a record that is seen as "before" the start of the current batch

And I believe flush size is mandatory for the storage connectors

---

Overall, systems such as Uber's Hudi or the previous Kafka-HDFS tool of Camus Sweeper are more equipped to handle small files. Connect Sink Tasks only care about consuming from Kafka, and writing to downstream systems; the framework itself doesn't recognize Hadoop prefers larger files.

Comment: When you're using `rotate.schedule.interval.ms` instead of `rotate.interval.ms`, you loose the exactly once delivery, did you find any workaround for this ? Thanks

Comment: It's been too long since I looked at this, but we used S3 connect, which I think still has EOS protections of some kind